# Segmentation fault .data

Tags: gcc, segmentation-fault, stack, elf

I have a little question about "segmentation-fault" issue, but I can find any answer.

I can deactivate the stack protection at the gcc compilation, with options `[-fno-stack-protector] -z execstack`:

```
GNU_STACK 0x0000000000000000  **RWE**    10
-->
GNU_STACK 0x0000000000000000  **RW**     10
```

*But*: For me, the `.data` section *is not* in the `GNU_STACK` segment! (Am I wrong?)

So, I don't understand why in one case I can execute a shellcode which is in the `.data` section, and I can't in another!

If it can help:

```
JC@ubuntu:~$ cat testShellcode2.c

    char bytecode[] = "\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xff\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x31\xd2\x52\xeb\x15\x48\x8b\x3c\x24\x48\x89\xe6\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xff\xb0\x3c\x0f\x05\xe8\xe6\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68";

    int main(){
        int (*ret)() ;
        ret = (int(*)()) bytecode;
        ret();
    }


JC@ubuntu:~$ cp testShellcode2.c testShellcode3.c

JC@ubuntu:~$ gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack testShellcode2.c -o testShellcode2

JC@ubuntu:~$ gcc testShellcode3.c -o testShellcode3

JC@ubuntu:~$ ./testShellcode2
$ exit

JC@ubuntu:~$ ./testShellcode3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

JC@ubuntu:~$ readelf -a testShellcode2 > elf2

JC@ubuntu:~$ readelf -a testShellcode3 > elf3

JC@ubuntu:~$ diff elf2 elf3

                  0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RWE    10

                  0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     10
```

Comment: In both cases, the bytecode string is in the .data segment.

Comment: Note that `-z execstack` is a linker flag and that the described behaviour is Linux-specific. May be you'd like to replace the `gcc` tag with `linux`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually interesting question, and a detailed answer is provided [here](http://blog.ioactive.com/2013/11/a-short-tale-about-executablestack-in.html).

The short story is that on older ix86 processors, any readable memory was also executable, and the Linux kernel gives you that behavior when it detects that your executable "doesn't want modern security protections".

Comment: That is indeed a very Linux-specific behaviour. On FreeBSD having executable stack does not affect the default memory protection and `.data` remains non-executable.